# Get object with specific value in ID variable

Tags: java

I'm reading a CSV file and creating objects based on the values on each line. I can't really name each object something unique so I do:

```
new User(x, y, z);
```

But how can I then find that newly created object? Is there a way to loop through all objects of a specific class (i.e. User)? Or at least find one based on the ID? (e.g. user(1))

In SQL I could simply

```
select * from X where ID=1
```

but how can I do this in Java after creating several nameless objects based on the data parsed from a text file?

Comment: You declare a variable to access it: User user = new User (x,y,z);

Comment: You put them in a container... like `X` in your SQL.

Comment: Just put them into a Map.

Comment: You want to pass the key (where key is the 'ID' you are generating) in and get the object associated with it?

Comment: `JAVA` and `mySQL` are totally different. You can't compare them.

Answer (score 3):

> Or at least find one based on the ID?

You have an identifier by created `User`?
So you should just store the objects in a `Map` where the key is the `User` id and the value is the `User` object.

With an `Integer` as id, it would give :

```
Map<Integer, User> usersById = new HashMap<>();

for (...){
   usersById.put(userId, new User(userId, x, y, z));
}
```

Then you can retrieve the user in this way :

```
User user = usersById.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, store the objects into a list.

```
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>(); 
...
...  // add each object to usersList
```

Later on, to imitate your `SQL` query, you can do something along the lines of:

```
Optional<User> result = usersList.stream().filter(x -> x.getId() == 1).findFirst();
```

This solution assumes you have an `id` field within your `User` class and a getter called `getId()`.

reading 
 - [**`Optional<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: I think he doesnt know how to store anything inside a application.